# Infinite loop with Firebase.on('child_added')

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a chat application where messages are stored in a Firebase collection.

There is a browser client that listens for the 'child_added' event on the
collection:

```
const chatRef = new Firebase()

chatRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) { //... })
```

I also have a server client that listens for the same event on the same collection. When the server client sees that a message was added to the collection, a callback fires to process the message, and push a new message into the collection:

```
const chatRef = new Firebase()

chatRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  const outgoingMessage = processIncomingMessage(snapshot.val())
  chatRef.push(outgoingMessage)
})
```

This causes an infinite loop, as the server will now attempt to process messages that it has added to the collection on Firebase.

Is there a way to avoid this? I think I need to restructure my data in Firebase, but I'm not quite sure how this should look.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to remove it. But it really depends on how you want this to work.

One way to do this is to make the server can ignore messages that it sent itself.

To do this, you'd have a list that keeps the push id of any items you're sending:

```
var pendingKeys = [];
```

Then when you send a message, you add its push id to this list:

```
var newRef = chatRef.push();
pendingKeys.push(newRef.key);
newRef.set(outgoingMessage);
```

Now when you get a `child_added`, you ignore the message when it's in your list of pending keys.

```
chatRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  var index = pendingKeys.indexOf(snapshot.key());
  if (index >= 0) {
    const outgoingMessage = processIncomingMessage(snapshot.val())
    chatRef.push(outgoingMessage)
  }
  else {
    pendingKeys.splice(index,1);
  }
})
```

You'll note that I also use a `splice()` to remove the key from the list at this point, since otherwise the list would keep growing indefinitely.